# Change Context Action Bar checkmark/done drawable?

Tags: android-actionbar, android, contextual-action-bar

Is there a good way to change the Context Action Bar checkmark drawable without creating a custom view for the whole Action Bar?

[image: contextual action bar]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.  You simply need to add the "actionModeCloseDrawable" item to your style.

```
<style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/my_custom_close_icon</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/my_custom_close_icon</item>
</style>
```